# MediaWiki Wiki Custom footer depending on category

Tags: footer, mediawiki, wiki, wikimedia

I was wondering if there was a way, to show certain parts of my footer, only when in certain categories.

E.g. a email link (mailto) only when in the `Category:FAQ`

I am using a custom Skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of [this snippet](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Snippets/Style_pages_based_on_categories) a CSS class is added to your body tag for every category the current page belongs to. You could then display or hide certain elements with help of the corresponding class.

Comment: How do i use the snippet? I do not have any .js files in my customSkin. My main file is a customSkin.php.

Comment: According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript the file Common.js is loaded in all skins. So I would try to insert the snippet there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own, custom skin, you can just check what categories your current wikipage belongs to, by calling 
[OutputPage::getCategories()](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classOutputPage.html#a71da4578e34312e09af793dc48fcc4b9). This will probably affect caching, though.

```
if (in_array( 'FAQ', $out->getCategories() ) {
  // do something
}
```

edit: @Florian points out below, that you should use OutputPage methods to output stuff, rather than echoing them, so I removed that unfortunate example. And as @Florian also points out, if you want this effect to persist also for users who might have selected another skin than your custom one, you'll have to use [a hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks#Hooks_grouped_by_function), e.g.`SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec`.

Comment: You can do this with hooks, too, which are also called in the near of the footer and provide access to an OutputPage object, too. Also I would recommend to use OutputPage to add content to the output, rather then using echo or print.

Comment: Thank you for this answer @leo & florian . How exactly would i use the hook? And where does it go? Into my customSkin.php ? Best regards.

Comment: You would create an extension (or, if the code is really small, you could even call the hook in LocalSettings.php). Have a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions